# При выводе на экран появляются лишние переводы строк

Tags: c++

Добрый день, помогите разобраться. При выводе на экран файла в обратном порядке появляются лишние переводы строки. И как следствие посчитанных символов при копировании файла недостаточно для вывода всего файла и начинается он не с начала. Как избавиться от лишних переводов строки и откуда они берутся?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char character;
    int count = 1;

    ifstream cppfile;
    ofstream txtfile;

    cppfile.open("Test.cpp");
    txtfile.open("Program.txt");
    cppfile.get(character);
    while (!cppfile.eof()) {
        count++;
        txtfile.put(character);
        cppfile.get(character);
    }
    txtfile.close();
    cppfile.close();

    ifstream Invert("Program.txt");
    for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
        Invert.seekg(count-i);
        char s = Invert.get();
        cout << s;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Привидите пример файлов и вывода в консоль.

Comment: Возможно, вы должны открыть файл как текстовый, чтобы включить трансляцию `\r\n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это проблема винды. Да. да. В винде перевод строки - это два байта, а именно CR+LF (ASCII 0x0D 0x0A). Библиотечные функции так устроены, что при прямом чтении они неявно конвертируются в `\n` - один символ (но при условии, что файл открыт в текстовом режиме. В бинарном все честно).

Когда же Вы читаете байты наоборот, то эта последовательность не распознается и вы получаете два байта. А вот как именно они интерпретируются - это уже детали реализации библиотек и терминала. Скорее всего оба символа были приведены к '\n', что собственно Вы и получили. Что делать? игнорируйте один с этих байтов. Но это не очень надежное решение. Более надежное - игнорировать эту последовательность и заменять ее переводом строки. Схематически это будет где то так

```
ifstream Invert("Program.txt");
char p = '\0';
for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
    Invert.seekg(count-i);
    char s = Invert.get();
    if (!(p == 0x0A && s == 0x0D)) {
       cout << s;
    }
    p = s;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Два дня ответ гуглил, хоть бы намек где-то на это был, уже и по разному реализовывал. Уже и упростил до минимума. )

Comment: Добавим, что еще и счетчик в текстовом режиме будет врать...

Comment: *"В бинарном все честно"* — удивительно тяжело на Windows [прочитать/записать байты без повреждений при обмене между программами](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Вы работаете в текстовом, а не бинарном режиме.
Но зачем вообще эти мучения с промежуточным файлом, двойным чтением?..
Вот то, что вы хотели на самом деле:

```
int main() {

    ifstream cppfile;

    cppfile.open("Program.cpp",ios::binary);

    cppfile.seekg(-1,ios::end);
    for(;cppfile;cppfile.seekg(-2,ios::cur))
    {
        char c = cppfile.get();
        cout << c;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В исходном куске нужно скопировать конкреный файл (решил сразу и посчитать символы) внести в него изменения и инвертировать. Скопировал вместе с копированием. Потом пытался все это упростить, но уже начал сомневаться и в подсчете при копировании. )

Comment: В текстовом режиме счетчик вполне может и врать. А лишний вывод (пустые строки) получается потому, что в файле идут символы `\n\r`, которые потом выводятся на экран опять же в *текстовом* режиме, с дополнительными символами.